# Working with strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a string which contains

```
abc: def - 01:00, ghi - 02:00
```

Any part of this string can change, except the order of the dividers in the string i.e. `:`, `-`, `:`, `,`, `-`, and `:`

How do I get the text before the first `:` and stick it into a variable for later use?

And also, how do I get the text between the first `-` and `,` and stick that into a different variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I get the text before the first `:` and stick it into a variable for later use?

```
var text = 'abc: def - 01:00, ghi - 02:00',
    firstChunk = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(':'));
    // firstChunk is "abc"
```

> And also, how do I get the text between the first `-` and `,` and stick that into a different variable?

```
var secondChunk = text.substring(text.indexOf('-') + 1, text.indexOf(','));
// secondChunk is " 01:00"
```

#### String function reference:

- [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- To get rid of excess whitespace (as in `" 01:00"`) use [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: @dotty it's not the string operation that most closely performs the task that the OP requires.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the string with Javascript's Regexp engine. For example:

```
    var expression = /expression_to_match/;
    expression.match(your_string);
```

Now you can access the matched elements with `RegExp.$1` etc.

A suitable regular expression for your string would be:

```
    /(\w+): (\w+) - (\d\d:\d\d), (\w+) - (\d\d:\d\d)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts' [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method.

`string.split(what we're splitting with)` (returned as an array)

So in your example we could use `string.split(":")[0]` to get the first part of the string.